# Bottleneck in Saving 10 M records in Redis DB

Tags: go, redis, slice

I have got a use-case where I am suppose to read data from Google BigTable and save to redis DB which will be further used by the team for internal processing.

For the Same below mentioned code is written

```golang
func (sS *someStruct) GetAndSetDataForCurrentDay() error {

    tm := time.Now()
    currDay := getPrefix(tm) //Some algo to get the prefix for BigTable Keys

    client, err := sS.GetClient("ClientName") // Big Table Initilisation
    tbl := client.Open("TableName")

    var redisRd []class_ad.RedisData //This might be culprit :(

    err = tbl.ReadRows(
        context.Background(),
        bt.PrefixRange(currDay),
        func(row bt.Row) bool {
            data, _ := sS.readAllRowData(row)
            rd, _ := sS.parseAllRows(data)
            redisRd = append(redisRd, rd...) // redisRd is global slice which I feel might be causing bottleneck
            return true
        },
    )
    redisClient, err := redisv2.GetConnectionx("redisConnName") //Redis Coonection Established Outside
    saveToRedis(redisClient, redisRd, time.Now())
    defer redisClient.Close()

    return err
}

func (sS *someStruct) parseAllRows(data []ColumnData) ([]class_ad.RedisData, error) {

    for _, v := range data {
        if v.ColumnName == "SomeColumn1" {
            someValue = string(v.Value)
            continue
        }

        if v.ColumnName == "SomeColumn2" {
            someOtherValue, err = v
            continue
        }
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
    return []class_ad.RedisData{"key1#Parallal", "Key2#Parallal"}, err
}

        
func (sS *someStruct) readAllRowData(row bt.Row) ([]ColumnData, error) {
    rowData := make([]ColumnData, 0)
    for columnFamilyName, columnFamilyData := range row {
        for _, column := range columnFamilyData {
            singleColumnData := ColumnData{
                Key:              column.Row,
                ColumnFamilyName: columnFamilyName,
                ColumnName:       column.Column,
                Value:            column.Value,
            }
            rowData = append(rowData, singleColumnData)
        }
    }
    return rowData, nil
}
    
func saveToRedis(redisClient *redisv2.Connectionx, rowData []class_ad.RedisData, now time.Time) {
    channel := make(chan bool) //Channel created
    for _, data := range rowData {
        go setKeyDataInRedis(redisClient, data, now, channel)
    }
    success, fail := 0, 0
    for range rowData {
        if <-channel {
            success++
            continue
        }
        fail++
    }
    close(channel)

    log.Printf("Success %v", success)
    log.Printf("Failure %v", fail)
}

func setKeyDataInRedis(redisClient *redisv2.Connectionx, data class_ad.RedisData, now time.Time, channel chan bool) {
    redisClient.ExpireAt(data.Key, endDate.Unix())
    if redisClient.HMSet(data.Key, map[string]string{
        "COLUMN_1": strconv.FormatFloat(data.Column1, 'f', -1, 64),
        "COLUMN_2": strconv.FormatFloat(data.Conversion, 'f', -1, 64),
        .
        .
        .
        .
        "CREATION_DATE":     now.String(),
        "MODIFICATION_DATE": now.String()}) != nil {
        channel <- false
        return
    }
    channel <- true
}
```

Number of records that we read are around 10M daily. Above code is following very high CPU usage causing service to get killed. Any solution on that line. Bulk saving data in Redis DB.

Comment: "Very high CPU usage" is a natural consequence of a heavy workload running efficiently. It's not a problem. Sounds like whatever is "causing service to get killed" is the problem in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Current design is suboptimal. I see two problems:

1. You have supper huge list stored under `redisRd` because you read all rows before you start to write to redis. This requires huge amount of memory. The code already presented does not justifies the need to have all rows in memory at the same time.
2. For loop in `saveToRedis` where you iterate over `rowData` spawns few millions of goroutines almost at the same moment. All of them will start to try to communicate with redis. Probably the client configuration protects your server from massive connection errors. But this does not change the fact that such number of goroutines requires coordination and few GB of memory.

Above problems probably also leads to extra CPU usage because of GC.

You could replace your global list `redisRd` with the `chan class_ad.RedisData`. The channel should be buffered and written by `tbl.ReadRows` callback. Before you start reading from BigQuery table, you should setup some small number of goroutines (you could start from 50)  which will be responsible from reading the data from this channel and writing them in redis. The number of such goroutines will define the number of concurrently executed set operation. Of course the result of such operation should not be reported back to the `tbl.ReadRows` but send to the another channel. You could also you [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to lower the number of packets send to redis. All this changes should greatly reduce memory usage and speed up the whole process. Below is my variation on how it could look like:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "sync"
)

type (
    // Row is a structure returned by big query client
    Row                struct{}
    bigQueryRepository interface {
        ReadRows(ctx context.Context, callback func(Row) bool) error
    }
    BigQueryReader struct {
        client bigQueryRepository
    }
    // Record is a structure used by the redis repository
    Record      struct{}
    RedisWriter struct{}

    RowsWriter interface {
        Write(ctx context.Context, row []Row) error
    }
    WorkDistributor struct {
        OnError func(err error)
        Workers []RowsWriter
        rows    chan Row
    }
)

func (r BigQueryReader) ReadRows(ctx context.Context, writer RowsWriter) error {
    return r.client.ReadRows(ctx, func(row Row) bool {
        if err := writer.Write(ctx, []Row{row}); err != nil {
            // Since there is only one goroutine which reads the data from bigquery,
            // translation to Record (potentially heavy operation) is done by workers. 
            // There are multiple workers, so they can make better use of multiple CPU cores. 
            log.Printf("Error writing a row: %s", err)
            return false
        }
        return true
    })
}

func (r RedisWriter) convertRowToRecord(row Row) []Record {
    // convert row to records
    return nil
}

// Write multiple rows. Method guarantees that either all rows are written or error occurs.
func (r RedisWriter) Write(ctx context.Context, rows []Row) error {
    // Use MULTI / EXEC commands to simulate transaction since we want to write all rows or none.
    // Send MULTI to redis
    for i := range rows {
        records := r.convertRowToRecord(rows[i])
        for j := range records {
            // Send SET operations using pipeline
            _ = j
        }
    }
    // Send EXEC to redis
    return nil
}

func (w WorkDistributor) Write(ctx context.Context, rows []Row) error {
    for i := range rows {
        w.rows <- rows[i]
    }
    return nil
}

func (w WorkDistributor) Run() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < len(w.Workers); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(idx int, worker RowsWriter) {
            defer wg.Done()
            for row := range w.rows {
                // Instead of writing single row there could be some batching mechanism to gather multiple rows together and pass them to worker.
                err := worker.Write(context.Background(), []Row{row})
                if err != nil {
                    w.OnError(err)
                }
            }
        }(i, w.Workers[i])
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

const numberOfWorkers = 50

func main() {
    wrks := make([]RowsWriter, numberOfWorkers)
    for i := 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++ {
        wrks[i] = RedisWriter{}
    }
    writer := WorkDistributor{Workers: wrks, OnError: func(err error) {
        log.Printf("Error writing to redis: %s", err)
    }, rows: make(chan Row, numberOfWorkers)}
    bigQuery := BigQueryReader{}
    err := bigQuery.ReadRows(context.Background(), writer)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

There are 3 main elements: rows reader, rows writer, and work distributor. Thanks to this you can easily write unit tests for each element.

What is worth to mention is that high CPU usage does not mean that something is wrong. You should monitor whether the CPU is spent for executing the application logic (which is good) or on GC, extensive memory allocation, etc which could be a sign that your application could be optimized.

Comment: Thank you @Jaroslaw. I got a little idea. Would you be able to enrich your answer with some dummy code snippet?

Comment: I've added some example. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Pipeline is what I won't be able to used beacause of some infra limitations. I am thinking if I can use batch over redisData within the `tbl.ReadRows(` . WDYT?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on why you cannot use pipeline? How batching in `tbl.ReadRows` will help?

Comment: SO for Redis we have avoided that at the wrapper we created for Redis connections. SO I ruled that out. For Batching. I mean as soon as batch count hit I will invoke Redis save for those records.

Comment: Ok, and what is the advantage of having batching in `tbl.ReadRows` instead of in `WorkDistributor` ? Of course, I may have mistakenly assumed that you would try to have something similar to my proposal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235838/discussion-between-jaroslaw-and-kunal-vohra).